# angular-ui Router with angular js giving isundefined error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
       <ui-view=""></ui-view>
</div>
```

The js code below is not running after I've added ui router.

Could anyone have a look at my code and explain what could be the issue?

I also checked script reference and they are correct. Page was working fine until I added UI router.

```
app.controller('SampleCtrl', [
'$scope',
function($scope){
$scope.test = 'Hello world!';

$scope.posts = [
{title: 'post 1', upvotes: 5},
{title: 'post 2', upvotes: 2},
{title: 'post 3', upvotes: 15},
{title: 'post 4', upvotes: 9},
{title: 'post 5', upvotes: 4}
];
 app.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
 function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 $urlRouterProvider.when("", "./Views/home");
 $stateProvider
 .state('""', {
  name: 'home',
  url: './Views/home',
  templateUrl: './Views/home.html',
  controller: 'SampleCtrl'
  });

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
 }]);
```

[Error showing in COnsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiOFI.png)

Comment: make sure you have added reference of `ui-router` after `angular.js` & then `.state('""', {` should be change to `.state("", {`

Comment: After your $scope.posts = []; you're not closing the controller, and you're beginning the app.config immediately. Is this -all- the code, or just snippets you've put up there?

Comment: Sorry but that's not the console error

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors, please double check you code again.

You code should be like:

```
app.controller('SampleCtrl', [
'$scope',
function($scope){
$scope.test = 'Hello world!';

$scope.posts = [
{title: 'post 1', upvotes: 5},
{title: 'post 2', upvotes: 2},
{title: 'post 3', upvotes: 15},
{title: 'post 4', upvotes: 9},
{title: 'post 5', upvotes: 4}
];
}]); <-- miss this close
...
```